# Switching boundary conditions in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, boundary-conditions

I am having a syntax problem in solving a second order non linear differential equation.  When I specify the command:

```
ESG[mh0_?NumberQ] := Module[{mH = mh0}, Clear[v, f, d];
f = v[m] /. (NDSolve[{equation == 0, 
         Derivative[1][v][0] == \[Omega] , 
         Derivative[1][v][mH] == 0} /. param, v[m], {m, 0, mH}, 
       Method -> {"Shooting", 
         "StartingInitialConditions" -> {v[0] == 8, v'[0] == 1.08}}][[
      1]]);
  {f - vH} /. {m -> mH} /. replacevH /. param]
sol = FindRoot[ESG[mH], {mH, 1}]
```

The program solves the free boundary value problem without any problem.  However, when I switch the ordering of the boundary conditions (I put v[mH] first, then v'[mH] in FindRoot), I get an error message:

```
ESG2[mH0_?NumberQ] := Module[{mH = mH0}, Clear[v, f, ESG2, d];
  f = v[m] /. (NDSolve[{equation == 0, 
          Derivative[1][v][0] == \[Omega]  , v[mH] == vH} /. 
         replacevH /. param, v[m], {m, 0, mH}, 
       Method -> {"Shooting", 
         "StartingInitialConditions" -> {v'[0] == 1, v[0] == 8}}][[
      1]]);
  {D[f, m]} /. {m -> mH}]
sol = FindRoot[ESG2[mH], {mH, 1}]
```

The error message reads:

```
During evaluation of In[112]:= FindRoot::nlnum: The function value ESG2[1.] is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {mH} = {1.}.
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Clearing `ESG2` in its definition seems a problem, but if I remove that, I still get that error (and plenty of others!!), mainly because `equation`, `replacevH`, and `param` are undefined.

Comment: This works fine: ``ESG2[mH0_?NumberQ] := Module[{mH = mH0}, Clear[v, f, d]; f = v[m] /. (NDSolve[{v''[m] + v'[m] + v[m] == 0, Derivative[1][v][0] == \[Omega], v[mH] == vH} /. {\[Omega] -> 0.1, vH -> 0.1}, v[m], {m, 0, mH}, Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {v'[0] == 1, v[0] == 8}}][[1]]); D[f, m] /. {m -> mH}];
sol = FindRoot[ESG2[mH], {mH, 1}]`` -- perhaps the issues lie in your particular definitions that are missing. (Unless it's `Clear[ESG2]`, of course.)

Comment: Michael thanks for your insights.  You were right it was just that I was clearing ESG2!  Thanks a lot.